# User control items in FlowLayoutPanel cannot be incremented using ExecuteReader database for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, odbc

my question about how to make a list of cart shopping item using a **FlowLayoutPanel** in which there are items using **User Control (Windows Forms)**

I create a shopping cart app. Here is how this application works:

1.) Double click **DaftarKeranjang** FlowLayoutPanel
[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTsyc.png)

2 - 3.) After the **Pilih** form appears, click the **OBH** cell. Then, click the **Pilih** button
[step 2 - 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2wEW.png)

4.) After that, Double click **DaftarKeranjang** FlowLayoutPanel
[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKdNz.png) .

5 - 6.) After the **Pilih** form appears, click the ID : **11** cell. Then, click the **Pilih** button
[step 5 - 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZjZg.png)

7.) Results like this appear : [Result 2a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m0JK.jpg) .
The correct result should be like this : [Result 2b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6IcG.png)

How to fix the problem of list items not growing after clicking the **Pilih** button so that the result of image [Result 2b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0DML.png) can be achieved?

The following is the program code that has been written using the Visual Basic programming language :

PilihObat.vb

```
Public Sub btnpilih_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPilih.Click
        Dim sqlcari, sqlnama As String
        Dim id_barang As Integer
        If dgvPilihDaftarObat.Rows.Item(dgvPilihDaftarObat.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString = "" Then
            MsgBox("data kosong!", vbInformation, "pilih data")
        Else
            id_barang = dgvPilihDaftarObat.Rows.Item(dgvPilihDaftarObat.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
            sqlcari = "SELECT id,namaobat,jumlahobat,hargaobat FROM tb_obat WHERE id = '" & id_barang & "'"
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = sqlcari
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If dr.Read Then
                ApotekerDashboard.ItemKeranjang1.NamaItemObat.Text = dr.Item(1)

                Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

ItemKeranjang.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ItemKeranjang
#Region "Properties"
    Private _title As String
    Private _itemcount As Integer
    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Title As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _title = value
            NamaItemObat.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property ItemCount As Integer
        Get
            Return _itemcount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _itemcount = value
            ItemObat.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
End Class
```

ApotekerDashboard.vb

```
Private Sub DaftarKeranjang_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DaftarKeranjang.MouseDoubleClick
        PilihObat.Show()
    End Sub
```

and the UI Designer **ApotekerDashboard.vb** structure:
[UI Designer scructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0DML.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `If dr.Read Then`, you want to do something like this:

```
Do While dr.Read
    Dim text = CType(dr.Item(1), String)
    Dim ik = New ItemKeranjang() With { .Title = Text }
    Dim label = New Label() With { .Text = ik.Title }
    Me.Controls.Add(label)
Loop
```

---

How to raise events:

```
Sub Main
    Dim ik As New ItemKeranjang
    AddHandler ik.TitleChanged, AddressOf Hello
    ik.Title = "Foo"
End Sub

Public Sub Hello(sender As Object, ea As String)
    Console.WriteLine("!" & ea & "!")
End Sub

Public Class ItemKeranjang

    Private _title As String
    Private _itemcount As Integer
    
    Public Event TitleChanged As EventHandler(Of String)
    Public Event ItemCountChanged As EventHandler(Of Integer)
    
    Public Property Title As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If _title <> value Then
                _title = value
                RaiseEvent TitleChanged(Me, _title)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ItemCount As Integer
        Get
            Return _itemcount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            If _itemcount <> value Then
                _itemcount = value
                RaiseEvent ItemCountChanged(Me, _itemcount)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    
End Class
```

Comment: why the error **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control** appears with the following code :

`Do While dr.Read
               ApotekerDashboard.ItemKeranjang1.NamaItemObat.Controls.Add(dr.Item(1))
               Me.Close()
Loop`

?

Comment: It's a bit obvious: `dr.Item(1)` is a string. You can only add controls to `ApotekerDashboard.ItemKeranjang1.NamaItemObat.Controls`. You need to figure out how to convert a `string` to a `Control`. Something like `new Label() { Text = (string)dr.Item(1) }` would do it.

Comment: Why is the syntax error? code : 
`New ItemKeranjang() { ApotekerDashboard.ItemKeranjang1.NamaItemObat.Text = (string)dr.Item(1) }`

Comment: I don't know what class `ItemKeranjang` is, but it should be more like `New ItemKeranjang() { Text = (string)dr.Item(1) }`.

Comment: @wilson_oey - No, I see `ItemKeranjang` - it's not a `Control` either. That won't work.

Comment: @wilson_oey - You need to convert your `string` into a `ItemKeranjang` and then convert that into a `Control` before you add it.

Comment: What is `NamaItemObat` and `ItemObat`?

Comment: Sorry, I've given you kind of hybrid C# and VB.NET code. You'll need to write it as proper VB.NET.

Comment: `NamaItemObat` and `ItemObat` are the respective toolbox **Label** and **DomainUpDown** which come from `ItemKeranjang` **User Control (Windows Forms)**. To see the UI designer structure of `ItemKeranjang.vb`, please look at this site : https://ibb.co/p0295wf

Comment: @wilson_oey - Your `ItemKeranjang` class is a data model and should not know anything about the UI. If you need to push values from a data model you should raise them using events and let the code that created `ItemKeranjang` to consume those events.

Comment: I'm still confused by this last statement. Can you provide a sample code for this case?

Comment: @wilson_oey - There you go. I've added code to show how you raise events.

Comment: why the error **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control** appears with the following code : ItemKeranjang.vb `Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ItemKeranjang
    Sub Main()
        Dim ik As New ItemKeranjang
        AddHandler ik.TitleChanged, AddressOf Hello
        ik.Title = "Foo"
    End Sub

    Public Sub Hello(sender As Object, ea As String)
        Console.WriteLine("!" & ea & "!")
    ...
` and ItemObat.vb `Do While dr.Read             ApotekerDashboard.ItemKeranjang1.NamaItemObat.Controls.Add(dr.Item(1))
...`
?

Comment: Because `dr.Item(1)` is a string and `Controls.Add(...)` expects a control.

Comment: so how should it be?

Comment: @wilson_oey - I let you know above. You need to convert your `string` into a `ItemKeranjang` and then convert that into a `Control` before you add it.

Comment: @wilson_oey - I've updated the answer with a bit more detail - it's not exactly what you need but it's closer.

Comment: why the error **ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.**?

Comment: Do I have to change the UI Designer structure to make the payment cart system easier including implementation to reporting? For example I want to change `DaftarKeranjang` FlowLayoutPanel to `DaftarKeranjang` ListBox. Later I want to make a report using **Crystal Report**

Comment: @wilson_oey - I don't think I can answer that.